# How can I write TNS strings in tnsnames.ora file when I have 2 Unix machines set up with the same DB instance name?

Tags: oracle, tnsnames

I have 2 servers X and Y. both the servers are set up with the Oracle DB instances with the name Z.
I need to have these inforamtions in the same tnsnames.ora file. How can I do this?

Comment: Give them different aliases.  In fact, you can give the same exact database two (or more) aliases in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<DB_X> =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = <hostnameX>)(Port = <port>))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = <Z>)
 )
)

<DB_Y> =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = <hostnameY>)(Port = <port>))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = <Z>)
 )
)
```